# Query to only return the 2 newest post attachments (images)?

Tags: attachments, get-posts

How can you make a query that runs through all posts in a category and outputs only the 2 newest image attachments (most posts in the category have no attachments)?

My current query is like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'category_name'  => 'butterflies', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'order'          => 'DESC', 
    'orderby'        => 'date' 
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    $argst = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'post_status'    => 'any', 
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID 
    );
    $attachments = get_posts( $argst );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>
            <a class="ptimg" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); 
                    ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            </a>
        <?php }
    };
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```